Jmeter 5.3 No column <responseMessage> found in sample metadata
I am having Jmeter 5.3 and trying to generate a Report from existing CSV file, using below command
jmeter.bat -g D:\Temp\TestPlan1.jtl -o D:\Temp\TestPlan1

But in console getting error
File 'D:\Temp\TestPlan1.jtl' does not contain the field names header, ensure the jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties are the same as when the CSV file was created or the file may be read incorrectly when generating report
An error occurred: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :No column <responseMessage> found in sample metadata <timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,success,bytes,sentBytes,Latency,Connect>, check #jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties to add the missing column
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . .

Here is sample of my jtl file
1721280793957,83,HTTP Request,200,true,1411,137,83,2
1721280794058,69,HTTP Request,200,true,1411,137,69,2
1721280793858,328,HTTP Request,200,true,1411,137,328,3
1721280794257,41,HTTP Request,200,true,1411,137,41,2

The number of columns (9) matches with <timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,success,bytes,sentBytes,Latency,Connect> then why it is saying to add the missing column. I have tried the solution mentioned in stackoverflow.com/questions/68904320
There is no entries for jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_ in jmeter.properties. These are present in user.properties but commented. Option2 also did not work for me.
Any help would be appreciated.

You cannot generate HTML Reporting Dashboard when Results File Configuration on machine where you run the test and the machine where you generate the HTML Reporting Dashboard is different.
You need to synchronize it by amending the relevant JMeter Properties
When it comes to your results file it's missing essential information required for building tables and charts, in particular the following columns are absolutely required:

responseMessage
threadName
grpThreads

So you need to re-run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode either with default Results File Configuration or at least ensuring that above 3 fields are present

I generated the jtl file in my local through jmeter command line. Trying to generate csv from same in local. Both are in same machine but still not working.
